# InDesign: how to run multiple find/change queries at once

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting, javascript, grep

The pesky `~c` in the grep find change is extremely helpful but limited.

I want to script multiple find change actions that replace the text found with complex formatted text blocks containing text, tables and objects.

I use grep a lot, but I'm limited by only having one clipboard item.

Is there a way to have multiple item on a clipboard and pull from them via a script?

Comment: In the past, in other contexts, I have used files with "magic names" in a specific location as the "clipboards," either by loading them dynamically, or merely switching to the MDI document with the specific name. For inDesign, this might look like a javascript that I could edit with logic to decide, once grep'd, which document to switch to, copy all, then paste in place. It might even look, in structure, like e.g. a "format fractions" script

Comment: Could it look like this...  Pardon my rough explanation.  (I'm not a javascripter)

1. Target file (Working file)
2. Open 'magic name' file
3. Select all > Copy > close file
4. Run GREP query
5. Rinse and repeat steps 2 - 4 as many times as number of changes

Does that look workable?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **FindChangeByList script** which comes packaged with InDesign (so everyone already has it). The script reads a **text file** that holds a list of "typed out" find/change commands that you can edit. These commands can be text, GREP, or glyph level find/change commands. Read more at [Indesign Secrets](https://indesignsecrets.com/a-major-job-gets-easier-with-grep-and-findchangebylist.php).

[image: FindChangeByList script]